# I'm having trouble with a top 1 join in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables table:

```
Customers 
(PK CustomerID, 
FirstName, 
LastName, 
CreatedDate, 
etc)

CustomerLocations 
(PK CustomerLocationID, 
CustomerID, 
LocationID)

Locations 
(PK LocationID,
 StreetAddress1, StreetAddress2, City, State, Zip, Country, 
CreatedDate, etc).
```

I need to write a query to return the `CustomerID`, their first and last name, and the address fields for their most recently created location, but I'm having trouble with the join to the `CustomerLocations` table.

For reference:

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName as CustomerName,
       l. StreetAddress1, l. StreetAddress2, l.City, l.State, l.Zip, l.Country
FROM Customers c
LEFT JOIN CustomerLocations cl ON c.CustomerID = cl.CustomerID
LEFT JOIN Locations l ON cl.LocationID = l.LocationID
```

The above obviously causes duplicating rows for each customer when I only want one to show the most recently created location's field for each customer.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the second and third tables to a subquery sorted in descending order and use `TOP 1` to get the latest location:

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName as CustomerName,
       loc.StreetAddress1, loc.StreetAddress2, loc.City, loc.State, loc.Zip, loc.Country
FROM Customers c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 l.StreetAddress1, l.StreetAddress2,
                        l.City, l.State, l.Zip, l.Country
           FROM CustomerLocations cl
           LEFT JOIN Locations l ON cl.LocationID = l.LocationID
           ORDER BY l.CreatedDate DESC) loc
       ON loc.CustomerID = cl.CustomerID
```

Answer (score 0):

`row_number()` is a typical way to solve this:

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName as CustomerName,
       cl.StreetAddress1, cl. StreetAddress2, cl.City, cl.State, cl.Zip, cl.Country
FROM Customers c LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT cl.CustomerId, l.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cl.CustomerId ORDER BY l.CreatedDate DESC) as seqnum
      FROM CustomerLocations cl JOIN
           Locations l 
           ON cl.LocationID = l.LocationID
     ) cl
     ON c.CustomerID = cl.CustomerID AND cl.seqnum = 1;
```

As a note, you should probably keep a `CreatedDate` in the junction table (`CustomerLocations`).  This would simplify the query and do effectively the same thing.